# Can I use QTimer to implement a multthreaded algorithm?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtimer

currently I need to implement a multi-threaded algorithm based on Qt. Maybe I should try to extend `QThread`. 
But before that, I'd like to ask, if I can just use two `QTimer`s `timer1`, `timer2`, and connect their timeout signal to the threads respectively, to implement a "fake" multi-threaded program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect the timeout() signal of `QTimer` to the appropriate slots, and call `start()`. From then on, the timers will emit the timeout() signals at constant intervals. But the two timers are run on the main thread and in the main event loop. So you can not call it multithreaded. Because  the two slots do not run simultaneously. They run one after an other and if one blocks the main thread, the other will never get called.

You can have a real multithreaded application by having some classes for different tasks that should be done concurrently and use `QObject::moveToThread` to change the thread affinity for the object :

```
 QThread *thread1 = new QThread();
 QThread *thread2 = new QThread();

 Task1    *task1   = new Task1();
 Task2    *task2   = new Task2();

 task1->moveToThread(thread1);
 task2->moveToThread(thread2);

 connect( thread1, SIGNAL(started()), task1, SLOT(doWork()) );
 connect( task1, SIGNAL(workFinished()), thread1, SLOT(quit()) );

 connect( thread2, SIGNAL(started()), task2, SLOT(doWork()) );
 connect( task2, SIGNAL(workFinished()), thread2, SLOT(quit()) );

 //automatically delete thread and task object when work is done:
 connect( thread1, SIGNAL(finished()), task1, SLOT(deleteLater()) );
 connect( thread1, SIGNAL(finished()), thread1, SLOT(deleteLater()) );

 connect( thread2, SIGNAL(finished()), task2, SLOT(deleteLater()) );
 connect( thread2, SIGNAL(finished()), thread2, SLOT(deleteLater()) );

 thread1->start();
 thread2->start();
```

Note that `Task1` and `Task2` inherit from `QObject`.