# Qt process events

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, events, emit

I have a `QString` object which is exported to  qml. In `C++` code while updating the value and emitting the changed signal for the property it does not update it because thread is busy: in that time I use a cost-operation in for loop. For that purpose I use `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` to be able to emit delayed signals on each iteration of the loop like:

```
foreach(const QVariant& item, _manifestFile) {
    setStatusString(QString("Checking file %1 of %2...").arg(currentProcessingFile++).arg(totalFilesCount));
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();  // TODO remove
    //...
}
```

Where `setStatusString` is setter of my `QString` variable I described above:

```
void Updater::setStatusString(const QString &statusString) {
    _statusString = statusString;

    emit statusStringChanged();
}
```

How can I remove that `processEvents()` and be able to emit signals? Any solution is appreciated: threaded, Qt-meta object things, etc.

Comment: try do it in thread. By default signal slot connection will enforce proper thread, so don't worry about that. The simplest approach is use of `QtConcurrent::run`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your object of the class `Updater` on the heap and move it to a new thread in order to prevent the for loop from blocking main thread and the UI. This can be done like:

```
updater = new Updater();
QThread * th = new QThread();
updater->moveToThread(th);

QObject::connect(th,SIGNAL(started()),updater,SLOT(OnStarted()));
QObject::connect(th,SIGNAL(finished()),updater,SLOT(OnFinished()));

QObject::connect(updater,SIGNAL(statusStringChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(updateString(QString)));

th->start();
```

Your initialization and termination tasks in the class `Updater` should be done in `OnStarted()` and `OnFinished()` slots respectively.

Now you can emit the signal with the appropriate value which would be queued and processed in the appropriate time. You can emit the signal in a timer periodically in certain intervals to prevent from emitting too frequent.

And the last point is that you should not call `Updater` functions directly when it is in an other thread. The correct way is defining the functions as slots and connecting a signal to that slot and emitting the signal when you want to call a specific function.

Comment: Pay attention if you directly update your UI too fast (from my experience) it could lead to some problems

Comment: Will the `updater`-methods work in thread where I make the call or in this `th` thread? I want to keep object interface without rewriting it signal-slot architecture. Also what if the `updater` is singleton?

Comment: You should not directly call the methods because the behavior is undefined and your application may crash. Either use signal/slot or use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(updater, "foo");` to call updater methods.

Comment: Okay, how to finish this action then? I mean, `updater`, `th` will stay alive forever. When I can delete `updater` for example?

Comment: You can call `th->quit()` which finishes the thread and emits `finished` signal. You can also connect the `finished` signal of thread to `deleteLater` slot of `updater`, it causes your object get deleted when the thread is finished.

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357986/can-i-use-qtimer-to-implement-a-multthreaded-algorithm/24358092#24358092